# Filter out and dynamically change appended results?

Tags: javascript, html

I will try to explain this as simple as possible.

I have a list of data that is from an object like so:

```
let burgers = [
   {
       "storeSpace": "Open Space",
       "storeName": "Five Guys",
         "storeImage": "images/burgers/five-guys.png",
         "storeLocation": "865 York Mills Rd, North York, ON M3B 1Y6",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM"
     },
    {
        "storeSpace": "Crowded",
         "storeName": "Rudy",
        "storeImage": "images/burgers/rudy.png",
        "storeLocation": "619 College St, Toronto, ON M6G 1B5",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM"
      },
      {
         "storeSpace": "Crowded",
         "storeName": "The Burger's Priest",
         "storeImage": "images/burgers/burger-priest.png",
        "storeLocation": "463 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M5V 2A9",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM",
         "pricing": true
      },
      {
         "storeSpace": "Open Space",
        "storeName": "Le Swan",
        "storeImage": "images/burgers/le-swan.png",
        "storeLocation": "892 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M6J 1G3",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM",
         "pricing": true
     },
     {
         "storeSpace": "Open Space",
         "storeName": "Le Swan",
         "storeImage": "images/burgers/le-swan.png",
         "storeLocation": "892 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M6J 1G3",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM"
      }
]
```

and that information is being displayed via a empty html string that looks like this:

```
var html = '';
function displayItems(obj, parent){
         var uniqueID = 0;
        obj.forEach(function(val){
            html += '<div class="food-section" onclick="compareModule(\'compare-food-gui\')" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>';
            html += '<div class="food-thumb">';
            html += '<img src="'+ val.storeImage +'" width="168" height="112"/>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="food-info" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>';
            html += '<p class="store-capacity">'+ val.storeSpace +'</p>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-unfilled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<p id="store-name" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>'+ val.storeName +'</p>';
            html += '<p class="store-desc" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>'+ val.storeLocation +'</p>';
            html += ' <p class="store-desc">Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM</p>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
        });
         let div = document.createElement('div');
         div.classList.add('cart-item');
         div.innerHTML = html;
         document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(div);
 }
 displayItems(burgers,"burgers");
```

Now I have a list of filter check buttons that when I click a specific one, I want to return a new list of items dynamically and live.

Those buttons graphically look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3adth.jpg

and the code is

```
<div class="filter-panel" id="filter-trigger">
                <h1>Pricing</h1>
                <label class="container"> Under $5.00
                    <input type="checkbox" id="under5" onclick="displayItems(burgers,'burgers', 'underfive')">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container"> $5.00 - $27.00
                    <input type="checkbox" id="fiveto27" onclick="fiveToTwentySeven(burgers,'burgers')">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container"> Over $27.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <h1>Portion Size</h1>
                <label class="container"> Under $5.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container"> $5.00 - $27.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container"> Over $27.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <h1>Rating</h1>
                <label class="container"> Under $5.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container"> $5.00 - $27.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>
                <label class="container"> Over $27.00
                    <input type="checkbox">
                    <span class="checkmark"></span>
                </label>

                <button id="filterBtn" class="confirm-btn-large">Show all 35 stores</button>
            </div>
```

I've tried many different approaches but nothing gets the right result. How can I achieve what i'm asking? I would like the results to simply update based on what options are clicked to be filtered.

Image of the results graphically: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAWK4.png

**Update: (What I have tried but does not help):**

```
function displayItems(obj, parent, t){
         var t = t;
            if(obj[y].pricing === t){
```

So I set it to check if the pricing is equal to t for type meaning a type of filter option. In this case "underfive" meaning, items under $5.

next I added ""pricing": "overfive"" to the object in one of the items.

Then in the html, I added

```
onclick="displayItems(burgers,'burgers', 'underfive')">
```

that is beside the filter button, and if I click it; it will indeed filter out the results accordingly but how will I manage this for every single change?

I would have to write duplicate code for the html results about 10 times. So I know that is not the correct solution.

Like im pretty sure I am not suppose to write

if(x = 1){
 copy paste the result code 
}

else if(x = 2){
copy paste the result code
}

and so on and so on. I want a function that can do it dynamically.

Comment: I could see only the items array,rendering function and filter section. Please provide some code, how you tried to get the result you desired.

Comment: I provided what I tried. Although it could work that way, its not beneficial without repasting the same blocks of code for every filter type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have price, rating and size property for each burger item so that it can be filtered out.

A global `filters` object/data is required to keep track of your filters.
Based on your snippet your rendering function has been modified to filter burgers if there is any filter and before rendering `burgers` element it needs to clear all the contents it had earlier.

On clicking the checkbox it will change the global `filters` object and call the render function.

```js
let burgers = [
   {
       "storeSpace": "Open Space",
       "storeName": "Five Guys",
         "storeImage": "https://www.seriouseats.com/recipes/images/2015/07/20150702-sous-vide-hamburger-anova-primary-1500x1125.jpg",
         "storeLocation": "865 York Mills Rd, North York, ON M3B 1Y6",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM",
         "price": "underfive"
     },
    {
        "storeSpace": "Crowded",
         "storeName": "Rudy",
        "storeImage": "images/burgers/rudy.png",
        "storeLocation": "619 College St, Toronto, ON M6G 1B5",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM",
        "price":"fiveToTwentySeven"
      },
      {
         "storeSpace": "Crowded",
         "storeName": "The Burger's Priest",
         "storeImage": "images/burgers/burger-priest.png",
        "storeLocation": "463 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M5V 2A9",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM",
         "pricing": true
      },
      {
         "storeSpace": "Open Space",
        "storeName": "Le Swan",
        "storeImage": "images/burgers/le-swan.png",
        "storeLocation": "892 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M6J 1G3",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM",
         "pricing": true
     },
     {
         "storeSpace": "Open Space",
         "storeName": "Le Swan",
         "storeImage": "images/burgers/le-swan.png",
         "storeLocation": "892 Queen St W, Toronto, ON M6J 1G3",
         "storeHours": "Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM"
      }
]
// a global filter variable
var filters = {
  price: [],
  size: [],
  rating: []
}   
function changefilter(type,value, checked){
  // if checked changes
  // if checked == true add to global filter object
  // else remove from global filter object
  if(checked) filters[type].push(value)
  else filters[type].splice(filters[type].indexOf(value),1)
  displayItems(burgers,"burgers",filters)
}

function displayItems(obj, parent, myfilter){
        // if filter exists then filter the burgers first
         var filteredBurgers = obj.filter(burger =>
            Object.keys(myfilter).every(
                key => myfilter[key].length === 0 || myfilter[key].includes(burger[key])
            )
        )
         // clear conents of parent element before rendering item
         document.getElementById(parent).innerHTML = ''
         var html = '';
         var uniqueID = 0;
         filteredBurgers.forEach(function(val){
            html += '<div class="food-section" onclick="compareModule(\'compare-food-gui\')" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>';
            html += '<div class="food-thumb">';
            html += '<img src="'+ val.storeImage +'" width="168" height="112"/>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '<div class="food-info" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>';
            html += '<p class="store-capacity">'+ val.storeSpace +'</p>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-filled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<img src="images/star-unfilled.png" height="17" width="17" class="store-rating"/>';
            html += '<p id="store-name" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>'+ val.storeName +'</p>';
            html += '<p class="store-desc" compare_id=' + uniqueID + '>'+ val.storeLocation +'</p>';
            html += ' <p class="store-desc">Hours: 11:00AM - 10:00PM</p>';
            html += '</div>';
            html += '</div>';
        });
         let div = document.createElement('div');
         div.classList.add('cart-item');
         div.innerHTML = html;
         document.getElementById(parent).appendChild(div);
 }
 displayItems(burgers,"burgers", filters);
```

```html
<div class="filter-panel" id="filter-trigger">
    <h1>Pricing</h1>
    <label class="container"> Under $5.00
        <input type="checkbox" id="under5" onchange="changefilter('price','underfive', this.checked)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container"> $5.00 - $27.00
        <input type="checkbox" id="fiveto27" onclick="changefilter('price','fiveToTwentySeven', this.checked)">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container"> Over $27.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <h1>Portion Size</h1>
    <label class="container"> Under $5.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container"> $5.00 - $27.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container"> Over $27.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <h1>Rating</h1>
    <label class="container"> Under $5.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container"> $5.00 - $27.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>
    <label class="container"> Over $27.00
        <input type="checkbox">
        <span class="checkmark"></span>
    </label>

    <button id="filterBtn" class="confirm-btn-large">Show all 35 stores</button>
</div>
  <div id="burgers"></div>
```

Comment: You're a wizard harry! Naw but thank you for the help :)